# jsdoc valid param types

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is there a list somewhere of valid types for param tags for jsdoc? For example,

```
@param {type} myParam Some parameter description
```

I know that things like `number` and `String` are valid, but what if I want to document that the number is an integer. Is `int` valid?

I've done some googling, but I can't seem to find a full list.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The JS Documentation tooling I've used just tokenizes the comments into strings anyway, making it possible to put anything you want in the {type} section.

You could stick with JavaScript types if you wanted like {number} or {string}, or if you want to specify you could do {integer}... but I would probably recommend something like:

`@param {number} myParam must be an integer`

cheers

Comment: I have noticed that tools are generally just tokenizing the strings, so it doesn't really matter. I just was hoping that there was some standard set of types. The javascript type system doesn't seem expressive enough (e.g. Number isn't very specific), but there are options as you've shown above.

Comment: One can put anything inside the {}, but it might be nice to know what the conventions are, no? Is there really no list? Like is there a convention for specifiying a Prototype object, or should that be @param {Object} ... ?

Comment: For the JSDoc generator (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc), in http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html is said, "The parameter type can be a built-in JavaScript type, such as string or Object, or a JSDoc namepath to another symbol in your code." In case of a symbol in your code, a link is generated to its definition. However, the built-in types still show up as strings, so there is no real difference e.g. between `{string}` and `{String}`. Also, e.g., PhpStorm recognizes them both, but complains about `{array}` while accepting `{Array}`.

Answer (score 36):

To answer the actual question

> Is there a list somewhere of valid types for param tags for jsdoc?

The documentation of `@param` states [here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html) that you can use built-in types and "[namepaths](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html)" (a.k. paths to types you have created/documented earlier and your own types you declared with `@type`.

If you look up `built-in Javascript types`, you get the following, for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures), you get the list of primitive types:

- Boolean
- Null
- Undefined
- Number
- String
- Symbol (new in ECMAScript 2015)
- Object

And here are some examples of namepaths:

- exampleFunction
- exampleClass#someInstanceMember
- exampleClass.staticMember
- exampleClass~innerMember

E.g. `@param {exampleClass} exampleParam Instance of your example class`

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case of specifying an "integer" type you can do:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Number} Integer
 */

/**
 * @type {Integer}
 */
var myvalue = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I did a search of a big codebase. Here are some of the most common ones I found:

- primitives

  - any
  - boolean
  - null
  - number
  - string
- common objects

  - Array
  - Document
  - Element
  - Function
  - HTMLDocument
  - HTMLElement
  - jQuery
  - Object
  - Window